# Sharing object between controllers doesn't work with a Service in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, data-binding, scope, angular-services

I have a simple app, and I want to share an object which can be set by a controller, and then access it from another controller to complete a task, here is the code :

index.html

```
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <ui-view></ui-view>
    <!-- All js files included and working -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myApp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/farms.js"></script>
    </body>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router']);

app.config(function config($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("farm", {
        url : "",
        controller : "myFarmController as FarmCtrl",
        templateUrl : "partials/farm.html"
    })
    $stateProvider.state("sau", {
        url : "/sau",
        controller : "mySauController as SauCtrl",
        templateUrl : "partials/sau.html"
    })
});

// Service used to share data
app.factory('Data', function(){
    return { farm: {idFarm:''} };
});

app.controller("mySauController", function($scope, $http, Data) {
    $scope.Data = Data;
}
```

farm.html

```
{{Data.farm}} <!-- this prints {"idFarm":5} -->
<div ui-sref="sau">GO TO SAU</div>
```

farms.js

```
app.controller("myFarmController", function($scope, $http, Data) {
$scope.Data = {"farm":{"idFarm":5}};
}
```

sau.html :

```
{{Data.farm}} <!-- this prints {"idFarm":""} -->
```

When I go to farm.html, I see that object shows as `{"idFarm":5}`, But when I click on `GO TO SAU` that I defined, it loads the sau.html, but I get an empty object `{"idFarm":""}`, as it was defined in the factory, so no data passed between the two controllers or the two partials, `farm.html` & `sau.html`.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In myFarmController, you don't use the service in your code.

Try this:

```
app.controller("myFarmController", function($scope, $http, Data) {
  Data.farm.idFarm = 5;
  $scope.Data = Data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The main point of assigning an object reference (`Data` service) to scope property is that it is shared between all scope properties that hold it.

What you're essentially doing here

```
app.controller("myFarmController", function($scope, $http, Data) {
$scope.Data = {"farm":{"idFarm":5}};
}
```

is assigning a new object to `$scope.Data`, it has nothing to do with original `Data` object. You should always stick to

```
$scope.Data = Data;
Data.farm = ...;
// or $scope.Data.farm = ...;
```

pattern to share the object between scopes.

Comment: I understand now, thank you very much for your help, I wish I can mark this too as an answer.